# Importing Flask app when using app factory and flask script

Tags: flask, flask-script

This is Flask app context

```
app = Flask(__name__)

with app.app_context():
    # insert code here
```

Most of the use cases of app context involves having 'app' initialized on the same script or importing app from the base.

My application is structured as the following:

```
# application/__init__.py
def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app

# manage.py
from application import create_app
from flask_script import Manager

manager = Manager(create_app)
manager.add_command("debug", Server(host='0.0.0.0', port=7777))
```

This might be really trivial issue, but how I should call 'with app.app_context()' if my application is structured like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask-Script calls everything inside the test context, so you can use current_app and other idioms:

> The Manager runs the command inside a Flask test context. This means that you can access request-local proxies where appropriate, such as current_app, which may be used by extensions.

http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#accessing-local-proxies

So you don't need to use with app.app_context() with Manager scripts. If you're trying to do something else, then you'd have to create the app first:

```
from application import create_app

app = create_app()

with app.app_context():
    # stuff here
```